# Can't select inputs after TransformY on chrome for a "card flipping" effect

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, css-transitions, css-transforms

I have a "card" design in which I have an `div` with two children, a "front" and a "back". A "card flipping" effect is achieved by applying a `rotateY(180deg)` transform to the card, hiding the back-face.

I've noticed a few differences between chrome and firefox. On firefox, the animation is smooth, on chrome, there's a flash of white. But most importantly, an input element on the "back" face of the card is not clickable in Chrome.

You can see the effect in each browser in these gifs:

[image: a card in chrome]
[image: a card in firefox]

Any ideas on what is going on?

Code available at this pen: https://codepen.io/elbasti/pen/poJjLmP

```js
function flipCard() {
  var element = document.getElementById("flipper-container");
  element.classList.toggle("flipper--flipped");
}
```

```css
.flipper {
  perspective: 1000px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}

.card {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  transition: transform 1s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  padding: 0px;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.card__face {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 12px;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.card__face--back {
  background-color: #9e0495;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  color: white;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.card__face--front {
  background: gray;
}

.flipper.flipper--flipped .card {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transition: transform 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<div id="flipper-container" class="flipper">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card__face card__face--back">
      <p>I am the back</p>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Back input">
      <p>The back one doeesn't work in chrome :(</p>
    </div>

    <div class="card__face card__face--front">
      <p>I am the front</p>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Front input">
      <p>The front input works.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<button id="toggle-flip" onclick="flipCard()">Click me</button>
```

Comment: For what I see the front card overlaps the back so you need to change z-index (the current one to 1 and hidden one to -1). But even with this if you have active backface-visibility: hidden; then you still can't use input for some reason (don't ask me why).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, that `.card` overlaps the back after rotation.

Maybe you could rotate not `.card` but `.card__face--front` and `.card__face--back`. I made some modifications in snippet.

```js
function flipCard() {
  var element = document.getElementById("flipper-container");
  element.classList.toggle("flipper--flipped");
}
```

```css
.flipper {
  perspective: 1000px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}

.card {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  transition: transform 1s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  padding: 0px;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.card__face {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 12px;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.card__face--back {
  background-color: #9e0495;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  color: white;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transition: transform 0.5s;
}

.card__face--front {
  background: gray;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
}

.flipper.flipper--flipped .card__face--front {
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  transition: transform 0.5s;
}

.flipper.flipper--flipped .card__face--back {
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
  transition: transform 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<div id="flipper-container" class="flipper">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card__face card__face--back">
      <p>I am the back</p>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Back input">
      <p>The back one doeesn't work in chrome :(</p>
    </div>

    <div class="card__face card__face--front">
      <p>I am the front</p>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Front input">
      <p>The front input works.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<button id="toggle-flip" onclick="flipCard()">Click me</button>
```